# If $f: A = (0, 1) \subset M = \mathbb{R} \rightarrow N = \mathbb{R}^3$ is continuous, then it maps Cauchy sequence to Cauchy sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Am I right with my arguments or is something wrong?

---

**proof.** Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a Cauchy sequence, then for every $\epsilon > 0$ exists an $N \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $n,m \geq N$, we have
$$d_M (x_n, x_m) < \epsilon$$
Since $f$ is continuous, given $\epsilon > 0$ we can take $\delta = \epsilon$, then
$$d_M(x_n, x_m) < \delta = \epsilon$$
So
$$d_N (f(x_n),f(x_m)) < \epsilon$$
Therefore, $(f(x_n))_{n\in\mathbb{R}}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Perhaps you want $f$ to be uniformly continuous?

Comment: No. I want to analyze when f is just continuous.

Comment: It's false in that case: Let $f(x)=(1/x,0,0)$ and consider the Cauchy sequence $1/n.$

Comment: Okay, it makes sense. I still can't quite handle the proofs using $\epsilon/\delta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a counterexample to the claim in the comments already.  To answer your question about where you might have gone wrong, you should examine why you think you're allowed to choose $\delta = \epsilon$ in your argument.

The definition of $f$ being continuous at $x_n$ tells you that for each $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $y$, if $d(x_n, y) < \delta$ then $d(f(x_n), f(x_m)) < \epsilon$.  It does *not* say that you get to pick the $\delta$.  As mentioned in the comments, it also does *not* say that the same $\delta$ will work for all $n$.

Comment: Ah! Got it. The concept is still not quite fixed in my head, I am trying to train it.